# Issue related to the shape of the of the residual array when using optimize.least_square with only 1 unknown parameter

Tags: least-squares, scipy-optimize

I am confronted with an issue I cannot solve myself... I am trying to iteratively solve a system of five non linear equations with only one unknown parameter but keep getting the following error message shown below. However, this error does not come up when I solve for 3 unknown parameters instead (using the same code but replacing some numbers by parameters to be estimated). My code is the following:

```
def equations (L):
  f1 = 5.519 - ((1.343876648526599/0.4)*(log(18/3.2441500954852724) - (-5*(148/L))))
  f2 = 8.940 - ((1.343876648526599/0.4)*(log(56/3.2441500954852724) - (-5*(148/L))))
  f3 = 11.658 - ((1.343876648526599/0.4)*(log(98/3.2441500954852724) - (-5*(148/L))))
  f4 = 12.590 - ((1.343876648526599/0.4)*(log(123/3.2441500954852724) - (-5*(148/L))))
  f5 = 12.983 - ((1.343876648526599/0.4)*(log(148/3.2441500954852724) - (-5*(148/L))))

  return (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5)

x0 = 300
root = spo.least_squares(equations, x0, bounds = ((10), (500)), max_nfev = 100).x
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-7315f1f7ce27> in <module>()

---> 27   root = spo.least_squares(equations, x0, bounds = ((10), (500)), max_nfev = 100).x
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py in least_squares(fun, x0, jac, bounds, method, ftol, xtol, gtol, x_scale, loss, f_scale, diff_step, tr_solver, tr_options, jac_sparsity, max_nfev, verbose, args, kwargs)
    809     if f0.ndim != 1:
    810         raise ValueError("`fun` must return at most 1-d array_like. "
--> 811                          "f0.shape: {0}".format(f0.shape))
    812 
    813     if not np.all(np.isfinite(f0)):

ValueError: `fun` must return at most 1-d array_like. f0.shape: (5, 1)
```